# File locked after perforce went into offline mode

Tags: eclipse-plugin, perforce

I have an eclipse project managed by perforce. I opened a few files up while it was in offline mode made changes and closed the files. My network came back up and now the permissions on the file is jacked.

I can change the permissions on the file system, but I have to do a checkout to get Team Sync to recognize the changes I made.

I still feel like I'm cheating. Is there something else I should be doing instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your connection is restored you need to tell Perforce to reconcile the offline changes you made. In Eclipse, this is done via **Team > Check Consistency...**.

Take a look at the [online manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.1/manuals/p4eclipse/topics/changesettings.html) for the details. This should save you from doing any manual nastiness with OS file permissions etc.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the online manual as well. Source control is  something I definitely need to get better at.